# How to Update values of dataGridView row in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have a dataGridview whose first column is Checkbox.Now as per my requirement i want to update the values of the dataGridView row on the selection of checkbox.I want it like as checkbox is clicked for a specific row ,that row should become editable and anything entered there should be updated on update button click.

Here is the code that i have for the gridview and Checkbox..

```
    private void btn_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Select", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
        dt.Columns.Add("UserName");
        dt.Columns.Add("EmpID");

        DataRow dr;

        //Connection lines
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Select"] = false;
                    dr["UserName"] = reader["UserName"].ToString();
                    dr["EmpID"] = reader["EmpID"].ToString();

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt; 
    }
```

Please help me .Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is make sure that the only editable column in your GridView is the one with the checkbox.
So, right after you are done with loading the data into the grid, this needs to be added:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    if (dc.Index.Equals(0))
    {
        dc.ReadOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        dc.ReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

This just sets all the columns except for the first one to be read only.

Now that you have your columns and the checkbox can be clicked, we need to somehow handle the changing of the checkbox state. Now, believe it or not, in order for this to work properly, we need to handle **two events**. There is a good reason for this. You see, if we handle the CellValueChanged event for the cells that contain the checkbox, it won't fire until the user leaves the cell after clicking it. This is what is considered to be the official end of editing the cell. That, of course won't do when checkboxes are in question, because we need to handle the event as soon as it's clicked. In order to do that, we will handle a second event - CellMouseUp, and in that handler force the editing to be finishe. It should all look something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            if (!dc.Index.Equals(0))
            {
                dc.ReadOnly =                                          
                    !(bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to implement this solution but it is not working at all in my requirement..